# progressdialog bar in android while loading webview keeps restarting or freezes sometimes

Tags: android, android-webview, progressdialog

I know that this question has been asked few times but none of the solution solved my problem so far.

I'm trying to load a url here in which it can differ from time to time as it is fetched from the feed. In my case some page loads without any problem and others while loading the **progress dialog bar loads for a second or so and freezes sometimes and then restarts once again and never dismisses** even after the url is finished loading.

This is the code that I'm currently working on :

```
 public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
       mwebview.loadUrl(url);
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);            
        webload = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        webload.setMessage("Please wait...");
        webload.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        webload.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        webload.show(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
       super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if(webload!=null)
            webload.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try declaring your ProgressBar out of the onPageStarted method and see if it works.

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. Declared it  in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method and couldn't declare outside of any method

Comment: As you are using different class for the WebViewClient you must use a constructor with the argument Context. MainActivity.this don't work out as expected.

Comment: Yeah it worked. I declared a constructor passing context as argument. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using **Toast**  and see if the program reaches the `webload.dismiss();` correctly.
As another question, are you doing all these stuff in AsyncTask?

Comment: I checked it with Log. it is reaching the statement. To your another question I'm trying to call this only on a button click that's why didn't use  AsyncTask

Comment: @Reaching-Out Well brother,I had the same problem loading the data from url. Since you are using a feed(Internet Based), I Strongly recommend using AsyncTask. I'll post the answer in a couple of minutes.